# Запросы из https сайта на http

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть вообще возможность произвести такой трюк, если да, то как?

Спасибо большое.

Comment: а в чём сложности? . На другие сайты чаще-нет, но есть ajax jsonp.

Comment: можеет показать на примере?

Comment: @RakzinRoman не работает: http://prntscr.com/byouax . в test.js находится alert(1)

Comment: [MDN советует перевести всё на HTTPS.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content)

Answer (score 2):

Такой трюк можно провести только через прокси. К примеру у вас на сейте будет проксирующий Url. Напрямую никак, браузеры все банят.

Comment: а как например можно осуществить? прокси есть

Comment: Проще будет написать метод на сервере, который примет некий набор параметров, отправит эти параметры на интересующий вас url(http|https), и в качетве ответа клиенту вернет данные полученные с другого сервера.

Answer (score 2):

Возможность есть. Необходимо выставить заголовок `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` на стороне сервера, принявшего ajax, который разрешит кроссдоменные запросы. Пример на PHP:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])){
    $originExpl = explode('//', $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
    $domain = end($originExpl);
    if ($domain == $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']){
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
    }
}
```

Для этого https должен быть подписан действующим сертификатом, иначе если только ajax по https идёт - снять ограничение безопасности у пользователя не удастся.

Comment: Да. мы всё это пробовали, но нужно отправить не обычный запрос, а запрос с защищённого сайта на не защищённый.